# Having problem in conditions in foreach loop php with two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to apply some condition in arrays in foreach loop . Actually I have two arrays which I will use later to send emails from the script. So My first array is containing smtp email Ids. and the second one is containing all email ids. Such as

```
$email_arrays=$this->camp->get_contact_details(9);
$smtp_array=$this->camp->get_sender_details(10);

/*  pre($email_arrays);
pre($smtp_array); */

$lastElement = end($smtp_array);
reset($smtp_array);


foreach ($email_arrays as $em) {
    $current = current($smtp_array);
    $current_smtp_email=$current['email'];

    $dl=$current['daily_limit'];//current daily limit e.g.5 or 10 etc

    //sendmail_test();            
    echo "Send email ".$em['email']." with smtp: ".$current_smtp_email . " <br/>";


    next($smtp_array);            
    if ($lastElement === $current) {
        reset($smtp_array);
    }
}
```

And I am having the output expected which is quite correct as per my requirement.But the main thing and trouble is I have set a limit on smtp email Id to send emails which I am getting from my another smtp table.

```
Send email test1@example.com with smtp: smtp1@gmail.com
Send email test2@example.com with smtp: smtp2@gmail.com
Send email test3@example.com with smtp: smtp3@gmail.com
Send email test4@example.com with smtp: smtp1@gmail.com
Send email test5@example.com with smtp: smtp2@gmail.com
Send email test6@example.com with smtp: smtp3@gmail.com
Send email test7@example.com with smtp: smtp1@gmail.com
Send email test8@example.com with smtp: smtp2@gmail.com
Send email test9@example.com with smtp: smtp3@gmail.com
Send email test10@example.com with smtp: smtp1@gmail.com
Send email test11@example.com with smtp: smtp2@gmail.com
Send email test12@example.com with smtp: smtp3@gmail.com
Send email test13@example.com with smtp: smtp1@gmail.com
Send email test14@example.com with smtp: smtp2@gmail.com
Send email test15@example.com with smtp: smtp3@gmail.com
```

I have successfully Made the account I want to expected.But the main thing is if I have applied a limit on smtp1@gmail.com(suppose it I have applied a limit 3) then email should be fired by next smtp in array and should store the email counts too.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**I want this output..
If I apply limit on smtp1@gmail.com of 3 then only 3 emails should be fired then iteration will continue using another smtp in array**

Answer (score 0):

Try an approach a little different, use first smpt to send email until the daily limit is reached, then move to the next one:

```
$lastElement = end($smtp_array);
reset($smtp_array);

$current = current($smtp_array);
$current_smtp_email=$current['email'];
$dl=$current['daily_limit'];//current daily limit e.g.5 or 10 etc
$send[$current_smtp_email] = 1;
foreach ($email_arrays as $em) {
    if ($send[$current_smtp_email] > $dl) {
        if ($lastElement === $current) {
            die ('No more SMTP to use today');
        }

    next($smtp_array);
    $current = current($smtp_array);
    $current_smtp_email=$current['email'];
    $dl=$current['daily_limit'];
    $send[$current_smtp_email] = 1;
}

echo "Send email ".$em['email']." with smtp: ".$current_smtp_email . " <br/>";
$send[$current_smtp_email]++;
```

}