# How do I set condition in foreach loop with array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two array one is for email list and the other one is smtp array
I want to apply certain condition in foreach loop and sending email but with 
the condition below is my code.

I have tried it with the code I pasted here but Its not working as expected as I want to apply limit on smtp to send only specified in smtp array limit array.

```php
$emails = array(            
    "test1@gmail.com",
    "test2@gmail.com",
    "test3@gmail.com",
    "test4@gmail.com",
    "test5@gmail.com",
    "test6@gmail.com",
    "test7@gmail.com",
    "test8@gmail.com",
    "test9@gmail.com",
    "test10@gmail.com",
    "tes11@gmail.com",
    "test12@gmail.com",
    "test13@gmail.com",
    "test14@gmail.com",
    "test15@gmail.com",
    "test16@gmail.com",
    "test17@gmail.com",
    "test18@gmail.com",
    "test19@gmail.com",
    "test20@gmail.com",
);

/*I have set smtp array with Its Daily Limit Count*/
$smtp=array(
    array("smtp1@gmail.com" => 2),
    array("smtp2@gmail.com" => 4),
    array("smtp3@gmail.com" => 5)
);        

/*When I Iterate the $emails array now */
//pre($smtp);
$counter=0;
foreach($emails as $email_key=>$email_value){            
    $smtp_detail=$smtp[$counter];            
    send_email($email_value,$smtp_detail);
    $counter++;  
}
```

As of now its working fine, but its not working with the limit per SMTP email.

How do I apply limit on email as per smtp as defined in `$stmp`? It should only fire 11 emails, as that is the total count (2 + 4 + 5 = 11), so `smtp1@gmail.com` should fire 2 emails, then `smtp2@gmail.com` should fire 4, and `mtp3@gmail.com` should fire 5.

Expected Output

```
$output_expected = array(
     test1@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp1@gmail.com,
     test2@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp2@gmail.com,
     test3@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp3@gmail.com,
     test4@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp1@gmail.com,
     test5@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp2@gmail.com,
     test6@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp3@gmail.com,
     test7@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp2@gmail.com,
     test8@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp3@gmail.com,
     test9@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp2@gmail.com,
     test10@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp3@gmail.com,
     test11@gmail.com => 'ok', 'smtp_used' => smtp3@gmail.com
);
```

So total email should be fired only 11 as my smtp limit count is 11 in the order I have specified

Comment: Just provide expected output.

Comment: Sir,I have updated the my question with expected output.

Comment: In your expected output you have `smtp1@gmail.com` 4 times but he is limit of 2, why?

Comment: This appears to be basically a duplicate of the question you asked only 2 hours earlier, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981424/having-problem-in-conditions-in-foreach-loop-php-with-two-arrays The next time, please don’t create such duplicates, edit your original question instead if you have stuff to add.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the first element from your `$smtp` array through `array_shift()` - this removes the first element from the array and returns that. Use `reset()` to get the value (which is the limit) and `key()` to get the key (which is the SMTP email).

Inside the loop, check if the counter has reached the limit - if it has, shift out the next value-pair, see if any was returned (if its `null`, there were no more values and we break out of the loop). If you got a valid result, use `reset()` and `key()` again.

```
$counter = 0;

$smtp_values = array_shift($smtp);
$limit = reset($smtp_values);
$smtp_email = key($smtp_values);

foreach ($emails as $email_key=>$email_value) {
    send_email($email_value, $smtp_email);

    $counter++;

    if ($limit == $counter) {                    // Check if the limit was reached
        $counter = 0;                            // Reset the counter
        $smtp_values = array_shift($smtp);       // Get the next pair of values

        // If there are no more values in the $smtp array, break out of the loop
        if (!$smtp_values) {
            break;
        }

        $limit = reset($smtp_values);            // Get the limit
        $smtp_email = key($smtp_values);         // Get the email
    }
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/YtSKT

Alternatively, you can do it through loops as well for earlier versions of PHP. Loop over the `$smtp` array, and for each iteration, get the email by using `key()` and the limit by using `array_shift()`. As before, this removes the first element of the array, meaning that when you use it enough times, there will not be anything else to loop.

Inside the outer loop, loop over your `$emails` and pass the values through to the function. Check if the limit has been reached, and use `continue 2` to use `continue` on the outer loop.

```
$counter = 0;

foreach ($smtp as $s) {
    $smtp_email = key($s);
    $limit = array_shift($s);

    foreach ($emails as $email_value) {
        send_email($email_value, $smtp_email);
        array_shift($emails);
        $counter++;

        if ($counter == $limit) {
            $counter = 0;
            continue 2;  // Continue the outer loop
        }
    }
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/XeOga

Comment: array_key_first() not working as my php verion is 7.1 and It is available in 7.3 .. Is there any alternative of this

Comment: Can you provide me a working demo..As I am stuck now badly

Comment: @NarendraSharma the manual for `array_key_first` has advice on how to achieve that functionality in earlier PHP versions.

Comment: @NarendraSharma I've updated my answer. Turns out the logic in the first way was a little flawed. Should be good now.

Comment: Its repeating emai lds ...see Your demo..user email should be unique ..once used will not come again

Comment: not working I just saw ..you were missing the order of smtps..like smtp1@gmail.com should send only 2 emails in order and smtp2 will send 4 and smtp3 will send 5.. in your demo smtp1@gmail.com is sending 4 times email but it should send only 2 email

Comment: In neither of the demos linked above the `smtp1` is used more than 2 times, `smtp2` is used 4 times and `smtp3` is used 5 times - they don't alternate, but that was never your request either - they do 2 at `smtp1`, then 4 at `smtp2` then 5 at `smtp5`. Check again - the results for both demos are the same, its just different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

We can prepare a send list array with email => smtp using foreach and array_fill and array_combine.

Once this list is done the array can be iterated and emails sent with the corresponding smtp.

```
$emails = array(            
    "test1@gmail.com",
    "test2@gmail.com",
    "test3@gmail.com",
    "test4@gmail.com",
    "test5@gmail.com",
    "test6@gmail.com",
    "test7@gmail.com",
    "test8@gmail.com",
    "test9@gmail.com",
    "test10@gmail.com",
    "tes11@gmail.com",
    "test12@gmail.com",
    "test13@gmail.com",
    "test14@gmail.com",
    "test15@gmail.com",
    "test16@gmail.com",
    "test17@gmail.com",
    "test18@gmail.com",
    "test19@gmail.com",
    "test20@gmail.com",
);

/*I have set smtp array with Its Daily Limit Count*/
$smtps=array(
    array("smtp1@gmail.com" => 2),
    array("smtp2@gmail.com" => 4),
    array("smtp3@gmail.com" => 5)
);        

$start =0;
$send =[];
foreach($smtps as $sub){
    foreach($sub as $smtp => $count){
        $send = array_merge($send, array_combine(array_slice($emails, $start, $count),array_fill(0, $count, $smtp)));
        $start += $count;
    }
}
var_dump($send);
```

Gives:

```
array(11) {
  ["test1@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp1@gmail.com"
  ["test2@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp1@gmail.com"
  ["test3@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp2@gmail.com"
  ["test4@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp2@gmail.com"
  ["test5@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp2@gmail.com"
  ["test6@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp2@gmail.com"
  ["test7@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
  ["test8@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
  ["test9@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
  ["test10@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
  ["tes11@gmail.com"]=>
  string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
}
```

To send emails just loop and send:

```
foreach($send as $mail => $smtp){
    send_email($mail, $smtp);
}
```

---

If the order is important then we can flatten smtp array to make the prepare easier.

```
//Flatten smtp array
foreach($smtps as &$sub){
    foreach($sub as $smtp => &$count){
        $newsmtp[$smtp] = $count;
    }
}

$start =0;
$send =[];

//Loop while there are $count left
while(array_sum($newsmtp)){
    foreach($newsmtp as $smtp => &$count){
        if($count){
            $send = array_merge($send, array_combine(array_slice($emails, $start, 1), [$smtp]));
            $count--;
            $start++;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($send);
```

Gives:

```
array(11) {
  ["test1@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp1@gmail.com"
  ["test2@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp2@gmail.com"
  ["test3@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
  ["test4@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp1@gmail.com"
  ["test5@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp2@gmail.com"
  ["test6@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
  ["test7@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp2@gmail.com"
  ["test8@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
  ["test9@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp2@gmail.com"
  ["test10@gmail.com"]=string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
  ["tes11@gmail.com"]=>string(15) "smtp3@gmail.com"
}
```

This can the be iterated and sent as suggested above.
https://3v4l.org/b4fQf

Comment: You just solved but you missed the order.See my Question .first email should be fired by smtp1 then smtp2 and then smtp3 ..

Comment: Why would that be important? It will still be coincidence what email will be sent with what smtp since it depends on the email list

Comment: @NarendraSharma see my new update, it should be what you want

Comment: Yes @Andreas You just did it.. Thanks a lot .you just made my day finally ..Quite Happy.

Comment: @NarendraSharma please accept the answer if it helped you